# setFetchMode PDO::FETCH_CLASS PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE return undefined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to use:

```
$stmt>setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,static::MODEL_CLASS);         
$customer = $stmt->fetch();`
```

To bind the data coming back into the constructor that's associated to static::MODEL_CLASS. Even if I just type the actual classname 'Customer' I get the error down here. Before the code gets the chance to fetch it goes into error. Without the setFetchMode i get data back. The database and model have the exact same properties in the exact same order. Does anyone know what is going on???

Error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to 
>          function Klant::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 8 expected in 
>          D:\Documents\Stack\Dropbox\Dropbox\Deltion\working\Hoofdstuk 
>          6\datamapperdesignpattern.php on line 14

```
class Klant {
public $ID;
public $voornaam;
public $achternaam;
public $adres;
public $postcode;
public $woonplaats;
public $email;
public $password;

public function __construct($ID, $voornaam, $achternaam, $adres, $postcode, $woonplaats, $email, $password) {
    $this->ID = $ID;
    $this->voornaam = $voornaam;
    $this->achternaam = $achternaam;
    $this->adres = $adres;
    $this->postcode = $postcode;
    $this->woonplaats = $woonplaats;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->password = $password;
}
function read($ID)
{
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE ID = ?");
    try {
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $ID);
        $stmt->execute();  
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,static::MODEL_CLASS);
    $customer = $stmt->fetch();
    return $customer;
}
```

^ Full code for reference. The constructor is a normal `public function __construct()`

IMPORTANT? NOTE:
This same exact code and this same exact database works with someone else. I have a fresh installation of Xampp. And the PHP version is 7.2.11.

Comment: *"The constructor is a normal public function __constructor()"* - The word is `__construct` and not `__constructor`. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php - I don't understand what you meant by that though. Where is the code for it?

Comment: @miken32 I noticed the edit; the OP's question is unclear. I don't know why they wrote what they wrote as quoted in my comment above. The question is unclear for me in that respect.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Based on the error message which specifically mentions "Klant::__construct()", I assume 'constructor' was just a typo and the function is named correctly, but it has 8 arguments, not none as they suggested.

Comment: @miken32 That's what I'm not sure about. Maybe they only wrote that as a way to explain they're using a constructor. I've seen questions before where they used `__constructor` instead of `__construct`, that's why.

Answer (score 1):

PDO will not send arguments to your constructor. Instead you can create your object and then use `PDO::FETCH_INTO` to save into an already existing object.

```
<?php
function read($ID)
{
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE ID = ?");
    try {
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $ID);
        $stmt->execute();  
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
    $customer = new Klant(...pass your desired arguments...);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $customer);
    $stmt->fetch();
    return $customer;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I know it can be done this way, but I find it super annoying that the example code doesn't work. Even though the same code works with others. Is it a PHPMyAdmin (MySql) thing? Even though it's freshly installed and it reads data just fine.

Comment: Does your object have public properties that match the names of the database columns?

Comment: Just tested and it works as expected for me: https://pastebin.com/e5sCn7PS

Comment: Yeha, that does work, thanks! But I was talking about the example from my book where they tell you to use fetch_class. But I guess my laptop is just being a turd or something.